# max length for POSTDATA to cgi.pm in perl

Tags: perl

I am using CGI.pm in perl for capturing the POSTDATA. What is the maximum limit for it in mega byte. Is it equal to `CGI::POST_MAX` How to change it ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/CGI.html) documentation:

> **$CGI::POST_MAX**
>
> If set to a non-negative integer, this variable puts a ceiling on the size of POSTings, in bytes. If CGI.pm detects a POST that is greater than the ceiling, it will immediately exit with an error message. This value will affect both ordinary POSTs and multipart POSTs, meaning that it limits the maximum size of file uploads as well. You should set this to a reasonably high value, such as 1 megabyte.

Example given - in same documentation - is:

```
$CGI::POST_MAX=1024 * 100;  # max 100K posts
```

Comment: I just checked it. Its working. I have other question, will it be depend on the size of payload my web server handle ? I am using apache tomcat

Comment: Yes, your webserver may have a similar limit. It might not though.

Comment: The default for `$CGI::POST_MAX` is `-1`, i.e. no limit.